# How do I create a browsable index of my External Hard Disks?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, hard-drive, external-disk

I have 7-8 External Hard Disk Drives. I would like to be able to know the content of each of the drives (files and folders) without having to connect them to my system (cumbersome).

Is there and program that can create a browsable snapshot of the directory listing?

Answer (score 2):

[**Virtual Volumes View**](http://vvvapp.sourceforge.net/)

VVV is an application that catalogs the content of removable volumes like CD and DVD disks for off-line searching. Folders and files can also be arranged in a single, virtual file system. Each folder of this virtual file system can contain files from many disks so you can arrange your data in a simple and logical way.

VVV also stores metadata information from audio files: author, title, album and so on. Most audio formats are supported.

It is possible to share the same catalog, stored in a network server, among Windows, Linux and OSX computers. The network server is simply a computer running a database server program. Click here for more info.

Features

VVV is available for Windows, Linux and for OS X (Intel only). You can exchange catalogs between Windows, Linux and OS X computers, and you can connect Windows, Linux and OS X computers to the same (Windows, Linux or OS X) server.

VVV is very fast, even with very large catalogs. Data are stored in a relational database, designed to handle millions of rows, so retrieving your information will always be a quick task.

VVV can show the content of your disks in three different views:

- The first is the physical view, click here for a Windows screenshot. This view shows the content of each disk, you can navigate in the folders structure and see the files contained in each folder.
- The second is the virtual view, click here for a Linux screenshot. In this view everything is organized as a single virtual file system. You can create folders and you can assign physical volumes or folders to each virtual folder. You can assign the same file to more than one virtual folder, and each virtual folder can contain files that are stored in different disks. The virtual view is a powerful tool that will let you organize your data in a logical way: it will save you a lot of searches.
- The third is the search view, click here for a Windows screenshot. In this view you can search the catalog looking for files that meet your specification.

[image: Virtual Volumes View]

http://vvvapp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Here you are. Hope this will help you:

1. [DiskCatalogMaker](http://diskcatalogmaker.com)
2. [Disk Manager](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/disk-manager-browse-disks/id540225569?mt=12)

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. Are there any opensource alternatives to this?

Comment: I am not aware about any for OSX at the moment. Please, mark your question as answered if this is what you're looking for.